# How do I make Microsoft Word show unicode correctly on all computers?

Tags: microsoft-word, unicode

I have a Word DOCX file that uses the Calibri font.  It has hairline spaces (unicode character 0x200A I think).  It looks fine on my computer with Word 2007 on Windows 7, a coworker's Word 2010 on Mac OS X 10.7, and coworker friend's Word 2007 on Windows XP.

However, it just shows up as a weird square with a question mark in it on **another** coworker's computer, kind of like this: [?].  Since this coworker is the one in charge of publishing our documents as reports, I need to figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the other coworker is using a computer without the Calibri font – either because it has old software and never had that font, or because it was removed for some odd reason. However, even in that case, Word should automatically switch to using another font that has U+200A HAIR SPACE, such as Arial Unicode MS. Without further information (like description of the software versions used and whether Calibri is installed), this remains a mystery.

Check out the font substitution information in Word in the other computer. The way to find it depends on Word version, but it can be found in Word settings. It is possible that for some odd reason, Word is using a font substitution table that maps Calibri to a font that lacks U+200A (like Arial).

Comment: I reviewed the problem computer and it has the same version of Calibri as the other Windows XP computers.  I will compare Office service pack levels and review the font substitution info and get back to this question.

Comment: @JohnWoltman, also check how Calibri works in that computer in general, e.g. by selecting it in Character Map and changing some text to Calibri in Word. It is possible that the font file is damaged.